# Where can I download previous versions of wkhtmltopdf from?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

[Wkhtmltopdf downloads](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) page allows me to download the current stable version of `wkhtmltopdf`. I am having a issue for which I suspect current version might be an issue. Where can I download the older versions of `wkhtmltopdf` from (more specifically for `Windows` 32-bit) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the archive section in the same page or obsolete downloads are available here: [**Wkhtmltopdf Downloads**](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/obsolete-downloads/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Rolling back to a older version fixed my issue. Thanks.

Comment: Link not found.